# Have Wordpress save posts as raw HTML directly into database instead of rendering on frontend

Tags: html, wordpress, content-management-system, tinymce, paragraph

In the `Visual` view in Wordpress when I press `<enter>` it appears as if a new paragraph is started (see image 1). But when I go to the 'Text' tab, no `<p>` tag can be found (see image 2).

[image]

[image]

I've installed the TinyMCE plugin because I thought it would provide me more control.
I also tried adding a codepiece to the `functions.php` file of my template (see here: http://www.adammershon.com/stop-wordpress-from-removing-br-and-p-tags/)

But I can't create paragraphs by entering text on the `Visual` tab, the only way is to insert p tags them manually on the `Text` view, which is unacceptable to my client.

Also when I press shift+enter on the `Visual` tab it goes to the next line, but on the `Text` there's no `<br/>` tag.

**Important note**
I've integrated my Wordpress with ASP.NET where I directly request the content from the Wordpress database. So the rendering of the HTML is NOT done by Wordpress.

How can I have Wordpress add the paragraph tags when only editing on the `Visual` tab?

(I did not place this post in webapps.stackexchange.com because fixing my issue most likely requires some programming.)

Comment: only p tags does not insert or all tags does not insert? please use input tag.

Comment: Updated my post: br tags also aren't added. What do you mean `use input tag`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Won't see `p` tags in text editor they will be generated at front-end

if you can't find `p` tags at frontend find and remove

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

this can be in

1. themes function.php
2. plugin you activated

for more info check [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)

**UPDATE**

To display the `p` and `br` tag we just need to install plugin which is [tinymce-advanced](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) and do some setting change. To change the setting just click check box for "Stop removing the `p` and `br` tags when saving and show them in HTML editor" and save. Now we can see the p and br tags in HTML mode and in database

Comment: I forgot to mention one important thing: I request the content directly from the Wordpress database, so the rendering is not done by Wordpress. Basically I need Wordpress to save the p, br etc. tags already in the database. Is that possible?

Comment: To display the p and br tag we just need to install plugin which is [tinymce-advanced](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/)  and do some setting change. To change the setting just click check box for "Stop removing the p and br tags when saving and show them in HTML editor" and save. Now we can see the p and br tags in HTML mode and in database.